# Install and Uninstall Your Windows Service Using Pre-build and Post-Build Events

Tags: windows, service, build

I have these scripts in pre-build and post-build events of visual studio for uninstalling and installing windows service

```
%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil /u "$(TargetPath)"

%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil "$(TargetPath)"
```

When I build first time it works;

When I rebuild, I get this file not found exception
 `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`: Could not load file or assembly '`file:///C:\Projects\DeviceManagement.ServiceHost\bin\Debug\DeviceManagement.ServiceHost.exe`' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

I can see this exe file in my debug folder though.

Comment: Unless you're making changes to the way the service actually installs, I'd just leave it installed rather than un/reinstall on every build. Changing the installation code should be a rare enough event that it could be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild does a clean, so it makes sense that the output isn't going to be there on pre-build. No need to do anything in the pre-build event.